# Caching server for snaps

Tags: package-management, snap, cache

A lot of packages have been added to the snaps store lately and it's great, but I work on an environment with very restricted bandwidth and everyone on the team usually benefit of other's downloaded packages. We have for instance [apt-cacher-ng](https://wiki.debian.org/AptCacherNg) to cache our .debs so they're downloaded only one time. Is there something like this for snap packages?